# How to group collection by columns

Tags: ruby-on-rails, collections, grouping, slim-lang

I am trying to group my product properties by the property set that they below to, i.e. I have Size as a property set and wish to group under it Small, Medium, Large etc..

This is the code I currently have but I am getting a few errors

```
- Property.all.group_by(&:property_set_id).each do |property_set, properties|
  h3= property_set.name
- properties.each do |property|
  = property.property_set.name
  .property_form.left.span-9.last
    - checked = property_set.name && property_set.properties.include?(property)
    label.mdl-switch.mdl-js-switch.mdl-js-ripple-effect for=property.name
      = check_box_tag "prototype[property_ids][]", property.id, checked, :class => 'mdl-switch__input', :id => property.name
      span.mdl-switch__label= property.name


  def edit
    @properties = Property.all
    @property_set = PropertySet.includes(:properties).find(params[:id])
  end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this line after grouping `property_set` will be the `id`

```
- Property.all.group_by(&:property_set_id).each do |property_set, properties|
```

Something like:

```
{ 1 => [<#Property>], 2 => [<#Property>] }
```

So you can't call `.name` on an integer value. You need to find it from db

```
h3= PropertySet.find(property_set).try(:name)
# or
h3= properties.find{ |p| p.property_set_id == property_set}.property_set.try(:name) # to avoid query
```